# How to install Concorde in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS?

Tags: software-installation

I need to install a TCP solver called Concorde, I see in its [download page](http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/tsp/concorde/downloads/downloads.htm) the option for Red Hat Linux.

How could I install the program in Ubuntu 14.04?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are only executable versions of Concorde and Linkern, not less, not more.

Compile your own version:

```
mkdir -p ~/src
cd ~/src
wget http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/tsp/concorde/downloads/codes/src/co031219.tgz
tar xf co031219.tgz
cd co031219
./configure
make
```

There is no rule to install (`make install`). All needed binaries are in subfolders of the source folder:

> This builds the concorde library (concorde.a), header file
>   (concorde.h), and several executable programs, including:
>
> ```
> TSP/concorde the TSP solver
> LINKERN/linkern the Lin-Kernighan TSP heuristic
> EDGEGEN/edgegen generates edge sets
> FMATCH/fmatch solves fractional 2-matching problems
> ```
>
> NOTE that to build the concorde TSP solver (for the exact solution of
>   TSPs), you must specify an LP solver in the configure step (either
>   QSopt for CPLEX).
>
> A short help menu for each of the executable codes can be obtained by
>   executing the code without any option, for example "concorde". A
>   typical way to run the concorde solver is to use: "concorde
>   myprob.tsp" where myprob.tsp is a TSP instance in TSPLIB format. To
>   test the concorde solver run "concorde -s 99 -k 100" (this should
>   generate and solve a random geometric TSP on 100 points).#

<sub>[Source](http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/tsp/concorde/DOC/README.html)</sub>

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I still had a problem. After installing the test failed.

`$ ./concorde -s 99 -k 100`
`./concorde -s 99 -k 100`
`Host: john  Current process id: 6386`
`Using random seed 99`
`Random 100 point set`
`XSet initial upperbound to 780 (from tour)`
`need to link an lp solver to use this function`
`CClp_create_info failed`
`need to link an lp solver to use this function`
`CCtsp_read_probfile or first_lp failed`
`need to link an lp solver to use this function`
`CCtsp_init_lp failed`

Comment: Your question was about installing (answered) and not about the usage. If you have further questions, ask a new one. If the installation was successful, accept the answer with a click on the check mark at the left side of the answer. **;)**

Comment: Isn't this is an installation issue? It looks like this is about specifying a solver during installation steps, action that apparently could not be acomplished correctly.

Comment: No, because there is no concrete installation. Read this http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/tsp/concorde/DOC/README.html

Comment: And also all other downloads on the page http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/tsp/concorde/downloads/downloads.htm are only compiled binaries. Not less, not more.

Comment: Thank you for the help A.B. I will try to solve the usage issues then.

Answer (score 2):

The instructions by @A.B. above are correct, but they do not include a description of how to install an LP solver. An LP solver is necessary to solve the TSP exactly using concorde.

To install an LP solver on Ubuntu, download the BETA version of qsopt from here: http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~bico/qsopt/beta/index.html (all the files listed under **Red Hat Linux, gcc 3.4.3 (AMD 64-bit)**) and put them in a directory on your machine. Then go to the unzipped concorde folder and run `./configure --with-qsopt=<full path to qsopt files>` making sure NOT to include a trailing / after the full path.

Next just run `make`. After that, cd into TSP and try running `./concorde -s 99 -k 100`

Good luck!

Comment: `/usr/bin/ld: /home/bram/src/libqsopt/qsopt.a(qsopt.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against '.rodata' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIE`